# Randomly return items in array based on number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to randomly display items from an array and I've been able to get it so that one item displays at random, now I want it to display a random number of items based on a number that I put in e.g when I input 2 I want 2 random items, when I input 5 I want 5 random items, etc...
How'd I go by this?

**Code**

```
const counter = 2; // Number of items I want to show
const Accounts = accountsData.sort(() => Math.random() - Math.random()).find(() => true); // This displays only one random item

<div className="text-area">
  {"Email: " + Accounts.email + " | Password: " + Accounts.password + " | Country: " + Accounts.country + " | Current Plan: " + Accounts.currentPlan + " | Has UHD: " + Accounts.hasUHD + " |  Max Streams: " + Accounts.maxStreams + " | Payment Method: " + Accounts.paymentMethod}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const fetchRandomValues = (arr) => (counter) =>
  [...Array(counter)].map(() => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]);

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const values = fetchRandomValues(arr)(2);
console.log(values)
```

Comment: Not working, it only shows one item and all the values come as "undefined"

Comment: @Hitman DD The example works in stackoverflow. Please show me the code you're trying to get working.

Comment: Here's the code on Codesandbox, I implemented it a little differently from yours but it's all basically the same and should serve the same purpose. I keep on getting 'undefined' whenever I try adding a number/counter.    https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-firefly-tld40?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @HitmanDD Ok, I have it working in this code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/random-values-generator-upo5w
Let me know what you think.

Comment: This works, but one last problem is that we sometimes get the same two or three values, its a rare occurrence but it happens, would there be a way to make sure that every random item is unique?

Comment: @HitmanDD Check out v2: https://codesandbox.io/s/random-values-generator-v2-hm7b7

Comment: Great! with this everything is working. Thanks so much man!

Comment: No worries pal, happy I could help.